# Vue 2 - remove class on hover and on click (with mulptile elements)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible to remove a class from the element with Vue? I need to remove the class on hover event, and bring it back when the pointer is not above the text.

Also, I need to remove class when the element is clicked.

This is an example I trying to run:

```
<span class="text-muted">All | </span>
<span class="text-muted">Visible | </span>
<span class="text-muted">Hidden</span>
```

When the page is loaded, the first **span** shouldn't have the class, until the another element is pressed.

Answer (score 5):

To remove the class when the element is clicked you can do it like this:

```
<span class="text-muted" @click="$event.target.classList.remove('whatever-class')">All | </span>
```

To remove the class on hover, just change the event name to `mouseover` :

```
<span class="text-muted" @mouseover="$event.target.classList.remove('whatever-class')">All | </span>
```

To add the class back use `mouseout` event:

```
<span class="text-muted" @mouseout="$event.target.classList.add('whatever-class')">All | </span>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: stackoverflow should have "give that man a coffee" button so we can send you a cup of coffee :D thanks you